# Change border color using JavaScript and save Cookie from Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, border

I use some JavaScript to change the color of some div's inside my HTML and have two problems with them. 
The first one is that I have a CSS triangle and I need to change the border color on click event but wont work with the next code:

```
document.getElementById('triangle').style.borderLeft = color;
```

Anyone any idea?

The next problem is the next: once the color has been changed, I'd like to save it as a cookie and load it when the visitor visits the next time.
This is my current JavaScript:

```
function change(color)
{
    document.getElementById('tinybox1').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('tinybox2').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('tinybox3').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('tinybox4').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('text').style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById('pinnable').style.backgroundColor = color;
    // document.getElementById('triangle').style.borderLeft = color;
}
```

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Why don't you try to use jQuery? will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change *just* the border colour without having to also specify size and type, use:

```
element.style.borderLeftColor = "#000";
```

Comment: By default border width might be 0, so only borderLeftColor will give nothing.

Comment: If the border width is zero, then it's not a CSS triangle as explained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question use `@VisioN` answer like this:

```
var color = "#000";
document.getElementById('triangle').style.borderLeft = "1px solid " + color;
```

For the second one about cookies try this (assuming that you want to use simple javascript) save this as **cookie.js** and import it in your html:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date( );
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) 
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for( var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt( 0)==' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie( name) 
{
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Now, to create cookie, do the following:

```
createCookie('cookiename', 'cookievalue', false);
```

To evaluate the cookie, do this:

```
 var cookie = readCookie('cookiename');

 // var cookie will be null if there is no cookie to read.
 if(cookie == 'cookievalue'){
   //do something
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question so far it can be done like that:

```
var color = "#000";
document.getElementById('triangle').style.borderLeft = "1px solid " + color;
```

Or combining with some styles.

**CSS:**

```
#triangle {
    ...
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
var color = "#000";
document.getElementById('triangle').style.borderLeftColor = color;
```